# Saiku Integration In SpagoBI

Tags: saiku, spagobi

I managed to integrate a saiku in SpagoBI 3.6. But the problem is that I couldn't avoid the authentication, the user has to double authenticate one for SpagoBI and the second for Saiku how can I disable the saiku authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Remove authentication pop-in.

For demonstration, POC, tests, you should need to remove authentication popin, and be always and directly logged as admin.

Open apache-tomcat-8.0.5/webapps/ROOT/js/saiku/Settings.js
And you will see one lines 139 to 142

```
if (window.location.hostname && (window.location.hostname == "dev.analytical-labs.com" || window.location.hostname == "demo.analytical-labs.com" )) {     
 Settings.USERNAME = "admin";
 Settings.PASSWORD = "admin";
}
```

Comment the "if" clause and its related closing bracket, reload the page, no authentication pop-in anymore.